# Owl carousel items content not able to copy

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Am using owl carousel in my website. In this am displaying carousel content with coupon codes. My issue is that am not able to copy this coupon code from website.

carousel code:

```
<div id="TopAirLine" class="topAirSlider owl-carousel owl-theme">           
<div class="item">
    <div class="topSliderImage">
        <div class="airhed">Use promocode <b>cb100</b>                      
            <span class="fa fa-plane"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="flightpric">description</div>                       
        <div class="flightpric">test</div>
        <div class="flvaluid"> <div class="lftvalid"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> Valid till: date.</div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topSliderImage">
        <div class="airhed">Use promocode <b>cb300</b>                      
            <span class="fa fa-plane"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="flightpric">description</div>                       
        <div class="flightpric">test11</div>
        <div class="flvaluid"> <div class="lftvalid"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> Valid till: date.</div> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you coping the coupon code? Could you describe more...?

Comment: Am trying to select the coupon code with mouse and copy (ctrl+c). not able to select the content with mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you need to disable the grabbing feature of `owlCarousel`. Try below code in your script file.

```
jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  touchDrag: false,
  mouseDrag: false,
});
```